# How to apply nested styles to my react form component,only main styles are appending not nested ones

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, css-selectors, react-css-modules

```
const formContainer = {
    maxWidth: "300px",
     backgroundColor: '#FD439B',
     padding: "10px",
    "& textarea" : {
      width: '100%',
      padding: '15px',
      margin: '5px 0 22px 0',
      border: "none",
      background: '#F1F1F1',
      resize: "none",
      minHeight: '200px'
    },
    "& focus" : {
      backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        outline: 'none'
    };
JS Code :
<div class="formContainer" style={formContainer}>
```

With this code only formContainer maxWidth,backgroundColor,padding is appending ,remaining code like textarea,focus styles are not coming.

Answer (score 0):

do it with Material-UI styles :

```
import React from "react";

import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {    
    
    maxWidth: "300px",
    backgroundColor: '#FD439B',
    padding: "10px",
   "& textarea" : {
     width: '100%',
     padding: '15px',
     margin: '5px 0 22px 0',
     border: "none",
     background: '#F1F1F1',
     resize: "none",
     minHeight: '200px'
   },
   "& textarea:focus" : {
     backgroundColor: '#ddd',
     outline: 'none'
   }    

  }
});

function TypographyTheme(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.classes.root} contenteditable="false">
      <textarea>
        "This div's text looks like that of a button.
      </textarea>
    </div>
  );
}


export default withStyles(styles)(TypographyTheme);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2jpmu?file=/demo.js)